# SQL: Return boolean if there is at least 1 record between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 2 tables:

Table 1 `priceList`

| ID | CurrencyID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | DF10CCE |

Table 2  `priceListItems`

| ID | priceListID | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | DESK |

I would like to write a statement in SQL to return a boolean (0 or 1) if the priceList has Items in, comparing with priceListItems based on their ID columns (For table A: ID = 3, and for Table B: priceListID = 3 )

How I can achieve that?

Comment: use a `CASE` and check the tables

Comment: provide your desired result

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: Question is not clear - do you want if 3 exists in either table?

Comment: @P.Salmon updated the question

Comment: Something like  [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=043e4055494c33b4b997fe0cc7389831) ?

Comment: @GuidoG this doesnt even run on ssms

Comment: Still too little sample data, and no specified result. A [mcve] is expected.

Comment: @xodesa The link to the DBFiddle says otherwise

Answer (score 1):

A simple left join and a case can fix this

```
select pl.*, 
       convert(bit, case when pli.ID is null then 0 else 1 end) as HasItems
from   PriceList pl 
  left join PriceListItem pli on pl.ID = pli.priceListID
```

Note that there is no `boolean` type in sql server, the closest is the `bit` type that can only be 0/1 and many software will show it as false/true

[Click on this link to see the query working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ec44e037e72c78e22e36ee64924e0ad)

The result is

| id | currencyid | HasItems |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | DF10DDE | True |
| 4 | blablabla | False |

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT a.ID FROM priceList a inner JOIN priceListItems b
    ON a.ID = b.priceListID
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 from CTE) then 1 ELSE 0 END as bool
```

Comment: The inner join will hide all rows in PriceList that have no relation with PriceListItems I am not sure that is what he asked, I think you want a left join

Answer (score 0):

Note that a simple left join is not sufficient because (I assume) query is supposed to return only one record per priceList record.
Try:

```
select
    pl.ID,
    case
        when pli.priceListID is null then 0
        else 1
    end as HasItems
from
    priceList as pl
    left join (select distinct priceListID from priceListItems) as pli on pli.priceListID = pl.ID
;
```

Comment: why select distinct in your left join ? You can simply left join without this, it only makes it more complicated and less performing

Comment: Because I am assuming the query is supposed to return only one record per priceList record, and I am assuming a one-to-many relationship between priceList and priceListItems.

Comment: I understand what you mean, in that case I would use an `outer apply` which will perform much better

Answer (score 0):

your data

```
declare @priceList table (
   ID         int NOT NULL 
  ,CurrencyID VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @priceList
(ID,CurrencyID) VALUES 
(3,'DF10CCE');


declare @priceListItems table (
   ID          int NOT NULL 
  ,priceListID int NOT NULL
  ,Product     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @priceListItems
(ID,priceListID,Product) VALUES 
(1,3,'DESK');
```

Use `full join` for distinguish the existence.

```
SELECT Iif(pl.id IS NULL, 0, 1)
FROM   @priceListItems pli
       FULL JOIN  @priceList pl
              ON pl.id = pli.pricelistid  
            --  where pl.id =3 --where condition
```

Comment: this seems to be good but i want only with ID=3

Comment: then use where condition and un-comment it

Comment: This where condition is not usefull, than he has to know which are valid before he runs the query, unless his question is not clear and he actually only wants that row

Answer (score 0):

You can use outer joins :

```
select pl.*, 
      (case when pli.priceListID is not null then 1 else 0 end) as flag
from  priceList pl left join
      priceListItems pli
      on pli.priceListID = pl.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select coalesce(max(1), 0)
from priceList p inner join priceListItems pi on pi.priceListID = p.ID
where p.ID = X
```

The inner join may even be redundant given the relationship.